# Test helper method with Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, minitest

I would like to test a helper method using **Minitest** ([`minitest-rails`](https://rubygems.org/gems/minitest-rails)) - but the helper method depends on [`current_user`, a Devise helper method available to controllers and view](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers).

**app/helpers/application_helper.rb**

```
def user_is_admin?                           # want to test
  current_user && current_user.admin?
end
```

**test/helpers/application_helper_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  test 'user is admin method' do
    assert user_is_admin?                # but current_user is undefined
  end
end
```

Note that I am able to test other helper methods that do not rely on `current_user`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you test a helper in Rails, the helper is included in the test object. (The test object is an instance of ActionView::TestCase.) Your helper's `user_is_admin?` method is expecting a method named `current_user` to also exist. On the controller and view_context objects this method is provided by Devise, but it is not on your test object, yet. Let's add it:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  def current_user
    users :default
  end

  test 'user is admin method' do
    assert user_is_admin?
  end
end
```

The object returned by `current_user` is up to you. Here we've returned a data fixture. You could return any object here that would make sense in the context of your test.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info in your answer! And thanks a lot for `minitest-rails`!! What terminology (like *stubbing*) would you use here, for what we are doing to `current_user`? By the way, I made `current_user` a `private` method, and I am using a global variable (`@admin = false`) in `ApplicationHelperTest` to control what `current_user` returns (`FactoryGirl.create(@admin ? :admin : :user)`) -- so I set `@admin = true` when I want to alter the behaviour, and I set it back when I'm done.

Comment: I don't have any terminology for it. It's just a method. Your helper method has a dependency on it existing.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that Helpers have to be tested as an instance from ActionView::TestCase. I am used to rspec and forget that always ;-)