# Stubbing current_user in Rails functional test using Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, stub

I'm having some trouble stubbing current_user in a Rails functional test for a controller.  I'm using Rails 4 and Minitest.  Currently, in the setup block I have this line.

```
ApplicationController.any_instance.stubs(:current_user).returns(users(:admin))
```

That's kind of working; however, I'm getting the following error from my view where current_user is referenced into a routing/url helper (edit_user_path(current_user)).

```
ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

What is the recommended way of stubbing current_user in controller/functional test?  Here's my full test.

```
require 'test_helper'

class Admin::SitesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @site = sites(:test)
    @request.env['HTTP_HOST'] = "#{@site.ssl_prefix}.testing.com"
    ApplicationController.any_instance.stubs(:current_user).returns(users(:admin))
  end

  test "should show edit form" do
    get :edit, id: @site.id
    assert_response :success
    assert_template layout: "layouts/admin/layout"
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you implemented `current_user` yourself, or it it part of the library?

Comment: i hope http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187127/test-helper-method-with-minitest answers your question

Comment: D-side, current_user is a method I have defined myself (not using devise) in   a helper (Admin::SessionHelper).

Comment: Thanks for this! A way to stub it in RSpec 3: `allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:current_user).and_return(my_user)`

Answer (score 1):

As always there are many ways to do this. The recommended way to stub the controller instance is to stub directly on the instance you are dealing with.

```
def setup
  @controller.stubs(:current_user).returns(users(:admin))
end
```

In controller tests you have access to the @controller instance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `def setup
    puts @controller
  end` prints `NilClass`

Comment: Are you using `ActionController::TestCase` ? FYI: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L264